How do I move radio button to right side of the box
I am currently in css and using latest css version
I have tried vertical align right and manipulated other solutions such as margins and other potential solutions posted  on this platform. But nothing is  working.
I am new to frontend Web development.

Please add the code you are working with, maybe a picture showing what you have and what your trying to achieve.

vertical-align: right makes no sense. The vertical axis is defined from top to bottom. Horizontally aligning would be right or left. However an input is an online element. As such it could be simply aligned horizontally with text align. Flex box would work too.

Radio buttons, by default, are styled as inline elements. That means that they can appear in the middle of a paragraph of text,  like this:


one two <input type="radio"> three four



But they are like any other element, so you can display and position them in multiple ways. You can have them display as a block element, or put them into a table or grid. You can use relative or absolute positioning.
You’ll generally use a <label> element with each of your radio buttons. You have two options for arranging these in your HTML. The first option is for the label to wrap the input, like this:
<label>
  <input type="radio" id="apple" name="fruit" value="apple" checked />
  Apple
</label>

The second option is that the label and the input can be separate but related elements, like this:
<label for="apple">Apple</label>
<input type="radio" id="apple" name="fruit" value="apple" checked />
  

Whichever option you choose also has implications for your styling. For example, in the three snippets below, the first two snippets use the label wrapper arrangement (because it is simpler), whereas the third snippet uses the independent label arrangement (because it provides more flexibility when it comes to styling).
The typical configuration of radio buttons is to have the button to the left of the label, like this:



fieldset {
  display: inline-block;
}

.f2 {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.f2 label {
  display: block;
}
<fieldset class="f1">
  <legend>Select a fruit:</legend>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="apple" name="fruit" value="apple" checked /> Apple
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="banana" name="fruit" value="banana" /> Banana
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="peach" name="fruit" value="peach" /> Peach
  </label>
</fieldset>
<br>

<fieldset class="f2">
  <legend>Select a fruit:</legend>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="apple" name="fruit" value="apple" checked /> Apple
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="banana" name="fruit" value="banana" /> Banana
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="peach" name="fruit" value="peach" /> Peach
  </label>
</fieldset>



If you want the button to the right of the label instead, you can move the position of the label text in the source code:



fieldset {
  display: inline-block;
}

.f2 {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.f2 label {
  display: block;
}
<fieldset class="f1">
  <legend>Select a fruit:</legend>

  <label>
    Apple <input type="radio" id="apple" name="fruit" value="apple" checked />
  </label>

  <label>
    Banana <input type="radio" id="banana" name="fruit" value="banana" />
  </label>

  <label>
    Peach <input type="radio" id="peach" name="fruit" value="peach" />
  </label>
</fieldset>
<br>

<fieldset class="f2">
  <legend>Select a fruit:</legend>

  <label>
    Apple <input type="radio" id="apple" name="fruit" value="apple" checked />
  </label>

  <label>
    Banana <input type="radio" id="banana" name="fruit" value="banana" />
  </label>

  <label>
    Peach <input type="radio" id="peach" name="fruit" value="peach" />
  </label>
</fieldset>



If you want the buttons to be horizontally aligned so that they appear a column, you’ll need to add a grid (or a table).



fieldset {
  display: inline-block;
}
fieldset > div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  gap: 0 1em;
}
fieldset label {
  display: block;
}
<fieldset>
  <legend>Select a fruit:</legend>

  <div>
    <label for="apple">Apple</label>
    <input type="radio" id="apple" name="fruit" value="apple" checked />

    <label for="banana">Banana</label>
    <input type="radio" id="banana" name="fruit" value="banana" />

    <label for="peach">Peach</label>
    <input type="radio" id="peach" name="fruit" value="peach" />
  </div>
</fieldset>



